# Existence of elements in a extension field

Tags: field-theory

Let $F/K$ be an extension field and let $D$ be a subset of $F$ and $z \in K(D)$. Why we can find a subset $\{d_{1},d_{2},...,d_{n}\} \subseteq D$ such that $z \in K(d_{1},d_{2},...,d_{n})$?

Comment: Unpack what it means for $z$ to be in $K(D)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, operations in algebra must be finite - we cannot take arbitrary sums or products of elements (in analysis, the concept of limit is available, in which case we **define** infinite sums and products via limits of finite ones). Thus, consider that $K(D)$ is the set of elements of $F$ that can be gotten by some *algebraic* combination (finite sums and products) of elements of $K$ and $D$. The specific element $z\in K(D)$ can only use finitely many elements of $D$.